# How to simulate an ARM processor run-time environment and load a Linux kernel module into it?

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel, gdb, arm

I try to load my `vmlinux` into `gdb` and use an ARM core simulator.

But I can't understand why do I get `Undefined target command: "sim".`:

Here is the shell output:

```
$ arm-eabi-gdb vmlinux
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.3.1-gg2
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "--host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=arm-linux-android".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /repo/kernel/kernel/vmlinux...done.
(gdb) target sim
Undefined target command: "sim".  Try "help target".
(gdb) help target
Connect to a target machine or process.
The first argument is the type or protocol of the target machine.
Remaining arguments are interpreted by the target protocol.  For more
information on the arguments for a particular protocol, type
`help target ' followed by the protocol name.

List of target subcommands:

target core -- Use a core file as a target
target exec -- Use an executable file as a target
target extended-remote -- Use a remote computer via a serial line
target record -- Log program while executing and replay execution from log
target record-core -- Log program while executing and replay execution from log
target remote -- Use a remote computer via a serial line
target tfile -- Use a trace file as a target
```

Comment: my question where do I get a simulator and how do i use it with gdb. I see it is not coming with the Android package

Comment: http://files.meetup.com/1590495/debugging-with-qemu.pdf

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/BuildArmPackages

Answer (score 4):

Your process is correct as per this [email](http://www.sourceware.org/ml/crossgcc/2000-q1/msg00019.html) and the [gdb target command](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Target-Commands.html) page in the manual.

However, the **gdb** configure script has an option *--disable-sim*.  The [crosstool-ng](http://crosstool-ng.org/) project uses this [option by default](http://www.sourceware.org/ml/crossgcc/2012-01/msg00088.html).  Most cross-compilers are build with this project <sup>Note1</sup> as it is a fairly lengthy process to do by hand.  It is quite possible that your **gdb** does not have the *simulator* built in.

There doesn't seem to be a command line option to print the **gdb** configuration.  However, running `strings -n 3 arm-eabi-gdb | grep -iw sim` should verify whether your **gdb** has the *sim* option or not; the command returns nothing if there is no *sim* option in the **gdb**.

**Note1:**  At least, Linaro, Ubuntu, Debian, and Ltib use *crosstool-ng*.  I am not sure about the Android suite.

Comment: Android has it's own toolchain varient maintained alongside the android sources.  Actually it has more than one - the widely distributed one used by application developers to make jni libs is not the same as the one used by device developers to build kernels.

Comment: Linaro also has [support for android](http://android.git.linaro.org/gitweb?p=toolchain/build.git;a=blob;f=README;hb=HEAD).  Apparently the scripts are much different, but it doesn't change the fact that if `gcc` is configured with *--disable-sim*, it isn't going to work.

Answer (score 3):

The ARM simulator in GDB doesn't emulate an ARM application processor capable of running the Linux kernel, e.g. I believe it doesn't emulate the memory management unit. For running Linux, use QEMU and its builtin gdb server instead: https://plus.google.com/100386424363328269117/posts/RhdQmjz4gBJ