# arm-none-eabi-gdb: Undefined target command: "sim"

Tags: c, arm, gdb, cross-compiling, simulation

I am trying to learn some about bare metal ARM programming with this tutorial: http://www.valvers.com/open-software/raspberry-pi/step01-bare-metal-programming-in-cpt1/

Luckily I successfully blinked the LED...

... but seems that I have got stuck when trying to use built-in CPU simulator:

```
zbyszek@ubuntu:~/opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_7-2013q3/bin$ ./arm-none-eabi-gdb
GNU gdb (GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors) 7.4.1.20130913-cvs
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "--host=i686-linux-gnu --target=arm-none-eabi".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
(gdb) target sim
Undefined target command: "sim".  Try "help target".
(gdb) help target
Connect to a target machine or process.
The first argument is the type or protocol of the target machine.
Remaining arguments are interpreted by the target protocol.  For more
information on the arguments for a particular protocol, type
`help target ' followed by the protocol name.

List of target subcommands:

target exec -- Use an executable file as a target
target extended-remote -- Use a remote computer via a serial line
target record -- Log program while executing and replay execution from log
target record-core -- Log program while executing and replay execution from log
target remote -- Use a remote computer via a serial line
target tfile -- Use a trace file as a target
```

I have read few threads on Stackoverflow but did not found solution yet.

For me most probably looks this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16217742/6632521

> However, the gdb configure script has an option --disable-sim. The
>   crosstool-ng project uses this option by default. Most cross-compilers
>   are build with this project Note1 as it is a fairly lengthy process to
>   do by hand. It is quite possible that your gdb does not have the
>   simulator built in.
>
> Note1: At least, Linaro, Ubuntu, Debian, and Ltib use crosstool-ng. I
>   am not sure about the Android suite.

But what this means? Should I build tool chain by hand with disabled option --disable-sim? Or is somewhere available release that contains builtin simulator?

Thanks in advance for all answers and I apologize in case of any inconvenience, this is my first question on Stackoverflow :)

Zbyszek

Comment: Why do you want to use `target sim`, when you could *debug* your code on the actual hardware with `target remote ...`?

Answer (score 2):

Your GDB does not have support for the built-in simulator target since:

```
(gdb) target sim
```

failed with:

```
Undefined target command: "sim".  Try "help target".
```

You must compile GDB with support for it with the configuration:

```
./configure --enable-sim
```

The crosstool-ng config is: `CT_GDB_CROSS_SIM=y`.

Here is a [minimal highly automated baremetal ARM crosstool-ng example with a C program](https://github.com/cirosantilli/newlib-examples/tree/2c9a355cf6ba27c655f58e28aa02db021f7f9288#gdb-builtin-cpu-simulator).

The default `gdb-multiarch` package on Ubuntu 16.04 does not have `--enable-sim`.